# Como mostar tabla al hacer submit

Tags: javascript, html

```html
   <tr>
        <td colspan "2"><input type="button" name="btn1" value="Enviar" onclick="obtenerdatos()"></td>
    </tr>

<table border="1" style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <td>Fecha Cita:</td><td><input type="text" name="fechaobtenido" id="fechaobtenido" ></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Hora de Cita:</td><td><input type="text" name="horaobtenida" id="horaobtenida" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Descripcion:</td><td><input type="text" name="descripcionobtenido" id="descripcionobtenido" ></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Seleccionar Especialidad:</td><td><input type="text" name="especialidadobtenida" id="especialidadobtenida" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Seleccionar Doctor :</td><td><input type="text" name="doctorobtenido" id="doctorobtenido" ></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
</form>
```

> Como puedo hacer que al aplastar el submit aparezca la es tabla ya que al presionar en boton guardar ya que la tabla debe estar ocultada y al presionar el boton guarde los datos llenados en el formulario y pararezca la segunda tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui una solucion, agregando un DIV y al interior la tabla

```js
function obtenerdatos(){
    $("#div_table").first().show("fast", function() {});
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<tr>
        <td colspan "2"><input type="submit" name="btn1" value="Enviar" onclick="obtenerdatos()"></td>
    </tr>
<div id="div_table"  style="display: none">
<table class="table table-sm" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Fecha Cita:</td><td><input type="text" name="fechaobtenido" id="fechaobtenido" ></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Hora de Cita:</td><td><input type="text" name="horaobtenida" id="horaobtenida" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Descripcion:</td><td><input type="text" name="descripcionobtenido" id="descripcionobtenido" ></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Seleccionar Especialidad:</td><td><input type="text" name="especialidadobtenida" id="especialidadobtenida" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Seleccionar Doctor :</td><td><input type="text" name="doctorobtenido" id="doctorobtenido" ></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
</div>
</form>
```